# Unable To Send Recorded Mp3 file using Mediarecorder To Server and Server Failed To Receive

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Uploading `.mp3` file to server Post man Working Is fine but . Through Retrofit Server Receiving Null , Creating Mutipart Request through retrofit

```
@Multipart
@POST("disposition")
public Call<StartCallingResponse> postcallDispotions(@PartMap HashMap<String, RequestBody> map,@Part  MultipartBody.Part file);


RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/mp3*"), file);
MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
Call<StartCallingResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance(getActivity()).getApiServices().postcallDispotions(map,fileToUpload );


  AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, manager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL), 0);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(196000);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();


        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
```

Comment: Change `MediaType.parse("audio/mp3")` to `MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")` and give it a try. If it doesn't work. Please [edit] the question and post server details as well.

Comment: Hi It doesn't  worked , i tried 
MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),
MediaType.parse("audio/mp3")
MediaType.parse("audio/ *")
MediaType.parse(" * / * ")
But Working  for image  is Fine

Comment: Hi another Sample mp3 File uploaded  but  recorded  mp3 file not  uploading server not  accepting . both files are same format size also similar, I checked postman  also same  issue.

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, to understand the problem, we need to check your server code. Can you please [edit] the question and post the file receiving part in server and screenshots of Postman client (working) here? And also tell us the Android OS version in which you're testing the code. If there any (Retrofit) logs please post it as well. Without these information it's hard to guess the root cause.

Comment: Hi Thanks , problem fixed . In Server code  mention allowed types all
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968196/how-to-make-codeigniter-file-upload-class-accept-all-extensions